# spark job cassandra error

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I am getting this error everytime I am running my scala program in spark with cassandra connector

```
    Exception during preparation of SELECT count(*) FROM "eventtest"."simpletbl" WHERE token("a") > ? AND token("a") <= ?   
    ALLOW FILTERING: class org.joda.time.DateTime in JavaMirror with org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader@23041911 of type class org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader 
    with classpath 
    [file: 
    /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20150711142923-0023/0/./spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.4.0-M1.jar
    ,file: 
    /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20150711142923-0023/0/./cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar,file: 
    /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20150711142923-0023/0/./cassandra-spark-job_2.10-1.0.jar,file: 
    /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20150711142923-0023/0/./guava-18.0.jar,file: 
    /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20150711142923-0023/0/./joda-convert-1.2.jar,file: 
    /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20150711142923-0023/0/./cassandra-clientutil-2.1.5.jar,file: 
    /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20150711142923-0023/0/./google-collections-1.0.jar] and parent being sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6132b73b of type class sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader with classpath [file: 
    /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/conf/,file: 
    /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar,file: 
    /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,file: 
    /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,file: 
    /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar] and parent being sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@489bb457 of type class sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader with classpath [file: 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar,file: 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar,file: 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar,file: 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar,file: 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/libatk-wrapper.so,file: 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/java-atk-wrapper.jar,file: 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar,file: 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar] and parent being primordial classloader with boot classpath [/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rhino.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/classes] not found.
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:163)
```

Here is my program

```
    /** CassandraJob.scala **/

    import com.datastax.spark.connector._
    import  org.apache.spark._


    object CassandraJob {
            def main(args: Array[String]) {
                    val conf = new SparkConf(true)
                                    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "172.28.0.164")
                                    .set("soark.cassandra.connection.rpc.port", "9160")

                    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
                    val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("eventtest", "simpletbl");
                    println("cassandra row count : " + rdd.count + ", cassanra row : " + rdd.first)

            }
    }
```

I have build the file using sbt compile, sbt package

Here is how I am submitting spark job

```
./bin/spark-submit --jars $(echo /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/jar/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')  --class "CassandraJob" --master spark://noi-cs-01:7077 /home/sysadmin/ApacheSparkProj/CassandraJob/target/scala-2.10/cassandra-spark-job_2.10-1.0.jar
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that you are using `org.joda.time.DateTime` which is missing in your submitted jar. Just add this jar to your dependencies: `... --jars $(echo /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/jar/*.jar | tr ' ' ','),/PATH/TO/DOWNLOADED/JODATIME/JAR --class "CassandraJob..."`

The other way is to include `org.joda.time.DateTime` in library dependencies in sbt and assembly *fat jar* with this library using `sbt assembly` [plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) instead of `sbt package`.